# How should an intern ask to be hired as permanent?

Tags: internship, hiring

I am an intern who will finish my internship next month and I would like to be hired as a permanent worker. I do have another one year still to finish on my bachelor, hence I hope I could secure a work placement once I graduated next year.

But I don't know how to approach my manager. I could say that my relationship with him is okay but we never had a one-to-one session. But I never report to him regarding my task's update; I reported to another staff member because he is in charge of interns but my manager is aware of all my tasks.

Can I ask him the following?

> I would like to be hired once I graduated next year. May I know what is the procedure?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Your approach is quite close. However, it somehow implies that you are sure that they will accept you as an employee. Maybe you consider changing to something like:

> Thank you, I had a great experience working here. As a result, I would like to become an employee after I finish the internship / graduate. **Will you please tell me what I can do, so the company will consider hiring me - and ideally, actually hire me?**

Answer (score 2):

If you don't get offered the opportunity to join the company, by all means, ask about it.

Request to have a chat with your manager, and start by asking for some feedback. And take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I have often had students say to me "oh I have been offered a permanent job / management training" at the end of their internship.

This has usually been those who have excelled at the internship, by creating something useful and new for example.

So, this type of offer tends to come from management to those interns that show the skills/dedication/promise that they are looking for. You can express your interest but don't ignore making an effort searching for other opportunities.